# MongoDB find: query not matching index according to queryPlanner of explain

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, indexing, mongodb-atlas

I have a **mongoDB** with a collection that is not working as fast as I would like. I've been reading about **explain()** and **queryPlanner** (didn't know about it until now). And **I have observed that my indices do not macth**.

I've tried the simplest index and it doesn't return match, but the **winningPlan** does seem to match. I will tell you how I did the steps:

1. db.candidatures.createIndex( {"client_id": 1 } )
2. db.candidatures.find({
   client_id: "800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222",
   }).explain() **(UPDATE: find by client_id not dni)**
3. Check queryPlanner result

```
{
  "plannerVersion": newNumberInt("1"),
  "namespace": "hrbot-prod.candidatures",
  "indexFilterSet": false,
  "parsedQuery": {
    "client_id": {
      "$eq": "800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222"
    }
  },
  "queryHash": "6C94666F",
  "planCacheKey": "65C00083",
  "winningPlan": {
    "stage": "FETCH",
    "inputStage": {
      "stage": "IXSCAN",
      "keyPattern": {
        "client_id": newNumberInt("1")
      },
      "indexName": "client_id",
      "isMultiKey": false,
      "multiKeyPaths": {
        "client_id": [
          
        ]
      },
      "isUnique": false,
      "isSparse": false,
      "isPartial": false,
      "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
      "direction": "forward",
      "indexBounds": {
        "client_id": [
          "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "rejectedPlans": [
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "dni": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_dni_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "dni": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "dni": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "candidature_id": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_candidature_id_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "candidature_id": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "candidature_id": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("-1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_update_at_-1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_update_at_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "matching": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_matching_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "matching": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "matching": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "matching": newNumberInt("-1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_matching_-1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "matching": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "matching": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "disponibilidad": newNumberInt("-1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_disponibilidad_-1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "email": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_email_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "email": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "email": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "candidature_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "email": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_candidature_id_1_email_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "candidature_id": [
            
          ],
          "email": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "candidature_id": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "email": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "candidature_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("-1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_candidature_id_1_update_at_-1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "candidature_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "candidature_id": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "disponibilidad": newNumberInt("-1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_disponibilidad_-1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "direccion": newNumberInt("1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_direccion_1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "direccion": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "direccion": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "direccion": newNumberInt("1"),
          "disponibilidad": newNumberInt("-1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_direccion_1_disponibilidad_-1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "direccion": [
            
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "direccion": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "cp": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_cp_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "cp": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "cp": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "disponibilidad": newNumberInt("-1"),
          "cp": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_disponibilidad_-1_cp_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            
          ],
          "cp": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ],
          "cp": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("-1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_update_at_-1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("-1"),
          "disponibilidad": newNumberInt("1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_update_at_-1_disponibilidad_1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ],
          "disponibilidad": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_update_at_1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("-1"),
          "candidature.estado": newNumberInt("1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_update_at_-1_candidature.estado_1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ],
          "candidature.estado": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ],
          "candidature.estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "create_at": newNumberInt("-1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_create_at_-1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "create_at": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "create_at": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "especialidad": newNumberInt("1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_especialidad_1_estado_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "especialidad": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "especialidad": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "direccion": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_direccion_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "direccion": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "direccion": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "candidatura_seleccionada": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_candidatura_seleccionada_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "candidatura_seleccionada": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "candidatura_seleccionada": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "provincia": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_provincia_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "provincia": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "provincia": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "candidatura_seleccionada": newNumberInt("1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1"),
          "direccion": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_candidatura_seleccionada_1_estado_1_direccion_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "candidatura_seleccionada": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ],
          "direccion": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "candidatura_seleccionada": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "direccion": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "client_id": newNumberInt("1"),
          "update_at": newNumberInt("-1"),
          "estado": newNumberInt("1"),
          "matching": newNumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "client_id_1_update_at_-1_estado_1_matching_1",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "client_id": [
            
          ],
          "update_at": [
            
          ],
          "estado": [
            
          ],
          "matching": [
            
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": newNumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "client_id": [
            "[\"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\", \"800a0d60-b5fe-11ea-ae04-42010a840222\"]"
          ],
          "update_at": [
            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
          ],
          "estado": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ],
          "matching": [
            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**It strikes me to see that it did not match the index:**
indexFilterSet: false,

**But in a winning plan it has an index with the name of the index with which it should have matched:**
winningPlan.inputStage.indexName: "client_id"

Can someone give me an explanation and help me to use my indexes correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can respond to the question regarding `indexFilterSet: false`, but something else looks off here.  Can you provide the full explain output (perhaps use pastebin.com)? It's not clear why a `.find()` using the `dni` field in the query would translate into a match against a `client_id` field in the document.

Comment: @user20042973 I have updated the information you requested

Comment: Ah great, that helps clarify the confusion!  Let me write up a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the `indexFilterSet` field is *not* an indication of whether or not the database used an index. The `winningPlan` section of the explain plan confirms the database did use one as expected.

##### `indexFilterSet`

The `indexFilterSet` field is defined [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/#mongodb-data-explain.queryPlanner.indexFilterSet) as follows:

> A boolean that specifies whether MongoDB applied an [index filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-plans/#std-label-index-filters) for the [query shape](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-query-shape).

Index filters, also known as 'plan cache filters' are a way for users to manually influence the query plan selection process. They are the server-side equivalent of client-side [hints](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/), though the two behave a bit differently.

Index filters effectively restrict the set of indexes that the database will consider for usage when planning a given query shape. The `indexFilterSet` field in explain output will only be `true` if an index filter has already been manually configured for the query shape:

```
test> db.foo.find({x:1}).explain().queryPlanner.indexFilterSet
false
test> db.runCommand({planCacheSetFilter:"foo", query:{x:1}, indexes:[{x:1}]})
{ ok: 1 }
test> db.foo.find({x:1}).explain().queryPlanner.indexFilterSet
true
```

Under normal operation, index filters and hints should **not** be used. The database itself is responsible for planning and executing queries and there is usually no need to help it do so. Indeed it is very uncommon to see index filters set in environments.

##### `winningPlan` and Index Usage

The `winningPlan` document is the one that contains [details the plan selected by the query optimizer](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/#mongodb-data-explain.queryPlanner.winningPlan). This is what you want to look at to determine what index (if any) was selected by the query planner for the query shape being explained.

As noted in the question, in your case the database selected a query plan using a tightly bounded index scan on the `"client_id"` index. This seems to be correct and normal, so there should be no problems or concerns from that regard.

##### Observations & Recommendations

That said, there *are* some other concerns that come to mind when looking at this explain output.

Most notably, there are 28 indexes that were considered for use for this query shape. I would recommend reviewing ["*Create Compound Indexes to Support Several Different Queries*"](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-compound-indexes-to-support-several-different-queries). It seems that you may be able to greatly reduce the set of indexes required to support your workload by removing redundant ones.

As a simple example, the `{ "client_id"S 1 }` index that was selected in the `winningPlan` is itself redundant. Any of the 27 other indexes that start with that field could have likely all have been used just as efficiently. Reducing the number of indexes will have benefits such as reducing the overhead when writing documents, reducing the number of items competing for space in memory, and simplifying the process for the query planner. The last of those things may be particularly relevant in your situation if you are currently examining explain output.

There is additional material (article and video) regarding [Unnecessary Indexes here](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema-design-anti-pattern-unnecessary-indexes/).

Comment: Thanks for your fantastic answer. Very clear and detailed. Now I understand better!
On the possibility of reducing indices.  My application is separated by clients and they can filter their users by different fields of their choose freely.
That's why I have created indexes on different combinations to ensure the use of indexes. If you search for "client_id+category+address" is an index composed of 3 fields equally optimized as 3 simple indexes? This is my biggest doubt.  
If there are 6 filterable fields, with different combinations. How do you recommend creating the indexes? Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it was helpful! Perhaps your follow-up deserves its own question?

Comment: Here create the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184419/mongodb-which-is-the-best-strategy-simple-or-compound-indexes